# Login to webpage using Java client

Tags: java, security

I need to programmatically login to a website using a Java client. The website does not have any API and uses a form authentication. After login in my client will need to download a file from the same website that is under a different URL.

I've tried basic authentication for the second URL but that did not work. I also tried implementing a client similar to this example: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-automate-login-a-website-java-example/ .                                   It does not seem to obtain the session for my client to use for the file download URL.

Here is the source code of what i am trying to achieve:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.CookieHandler;
import java.net.CookieManager;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.parser.Parser;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
        String authURL = "https://hostname/webapp/loginUrl?parameters=values";
        String fileURL = "https://hostname/webapp/downloadFile?parameters=values";
        String username = "username";
        String password = "password";


        // downloading the login page
        List<String> cookies = null;
        CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());
        URL url = new URL(authURL);
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        cookies = conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");
        String loginPage = response.toString();



        // extracting form parameters
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(loginPage, "", Parser.xmlParser());
        Element loginform = doc.getElementById("Logon");
        Elements inputElements = loginform.getElementsByTag("input");
        List<String> paramList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Element inputElement: inputElements) {
            String key = inputElement.attr("name");
            String value = inputElement.attr("value");
            if(key.equals("logonId")) {
                value = username;
            }

            if(key.equals("logonPassword")) {
                value = password;
            }
            paramList.add(key + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
        }

        StringBuilder params = new StringBuilder();
        for(String param: paramList) {
            if(params.length() == 0) {
                params.append(param);
            } else {
                params.append("&" + param);
            }
        }



        // send post request to login
        conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        for(String cookie : cookies) {
            conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
        }
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(params.length()));
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);

        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(params.toString());
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();


        // download the file
        url = new URL(fileURL);
        conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        if(cookies != null) {
            for(String cookie: cookies) {
                conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
            }
        }

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        response = new StringBuffer();

        while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        cookies = conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");


        // save the file to local disk
        BufferedWriter bwr = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("c:/temp/content")));
        bwr.write(response.toString());
        bwr.flush();
        bwr.close();
    }
}
```

What is the correct approach for this type of scenario? Should my client be capturing and maintaining a cookie/session/session token that the page creates?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your code and the browser dev tools traces that show how what a browser does to successfully login and download the file?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a session or something similar depends on the website. Therefore you should first check what the web page really does.

My common approach is to use a web-proxy like Fiddler or Burp to investigate all network calls while browsing the page manually. Then I can redo certain interesting calls from within the proxy and remove step-by-step the headers to see what is really necessary.
If the request is striped down to the maximum and all required headers/data has been identified you can re-program the call in Java.

Using Apache commons http with cookie manager would be my preferred Java library for implementing this on Java side (but that depends on the needs of the web site).

If the web page is very very complex and obfuscated sometimes using a real browser is the simplest way. Depending on the web page you ca tools like [ui4j](https://github.com/ui4j/ui4j) or [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) (using [jBrowserDriver](https://github.com/MachinePublishers/jBrowserDriver) or Firefox as engine) to remote control a web-browser and simulate a surfing user.